# can't locate node [naoqi_joint_states_cpp]

Tags: ros, nao-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
we are trying to run nao_driver on our remote machine, connecting to your real Nao with :

NAO_IP=192.168.1.10 roslaunch nao_driver nao_driver.launch   ( as said in http://wiki.ros.org/naoqi_driver)

but we get :

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [naoqi_driver/naoqi_joint_states_cpp]: can't locate node [naoqi_joint_states_cpp] in package [naoqi_driver]

we tried to update/upgrade but nothing changed. We are working under indigo and naoqi1.14 and we setup the PYTHONPATH to the pynaoqi path.

What can I try ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200891/can%27t-locate-node-%5Bnaoqi_joint_states_cpp%5D/) by [scarlett](https://answers.ros.org/users/12086/scarlett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

naoqi_joint_state_cpp is a c++ node. So changing your PYTHONPATH won't help you in this matter.

You should add an environment variable AL_DIR and link it to the folder of the naoqi c++ SDK.

Otherwise when you run catkin_make you should have the following error message :
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'naoqi_driver'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(naoqi_bridge/naoqi_driver)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Could not find NAOqi's alcommon
-- Could not find NAOqi's alvision
-- Could not find NAOqi's alproxies
-- Could not find NAOqi's alerror
-- Could not find NAOqi's alvalue
-- Cannot find NAOqi C++ sdk; C++ nodes will NOT be built

This means that the naoqi_joint_states_cpp node won't be built.

Hope this helps,

Cheers,
Mikael

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1